# Memcached Permissions Issue... Maybe?

Tags: memcached

If I have permissions to access memcached ...

```
telnet localhost 11211 // success
```

would I necessarily be able to view (GET) all keys in the cache?

On my local box, I am able to telnet onto memcache and perform "GET" operations. However, on my remote box where I'm ssh'd, all of my "GET" operations are returning "END," i.e. no results.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Comment the following line in you memcached.conf file and restart your memcached server.

```
# -l 127.0.0.1
```

Refer this post: [Can't get cached items back from memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617035/cant-get-cached-items-back-from-memcached/13622047#13622047)

Comment: I don't have sudo. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: You can restart memcached with with parameter "-l 0.0.0.0". If you don't have rights to do that also I guess you are out of luck here.

Comment: There is work around. You can have a ssh tunnel from your remote box to the server.